# How to calculate number of possible combinations?

Tags: php, combinations

I'm update my secret santa web-app so now there relationship restrictions. So basically, I need to know first if the draw is possible. Example

```
array('Al', 'Bob', 'Carl', 'Dana', 'Ella');
```

First: How many different draws can occur?

Second: if Al is in couple with Dana and Carl with Ella, knowing they can't draw each others name, how many draws can occur?

Any ideas how to accomplish that?